# IE11: Object doesn't support property or method 'replaceWith'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have a simple function that moves modals to a modal container when they are dynamically loaded. It works in Edge, Chrome, and Firefox. However, in IE11, I get the error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'replaceWith'". Our customer requires IE11 support.

What could be causing the error?

```
function moveModals() {
    $('#mainBody .modal').each(function () {
        if ($("#modalsContainer>#" + this.id).exists())
            $("#modalsContainer>#" + this.id)[0].replaceWith(this);
        else
            $(this).appendTo("#modalsContainer");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$("#modalsContainer>#" + this.id).replaceWith(this);
```

This way you rely only on jQuery (omitting the `[0]` from what you wrote). The way you wrote you are calling the replaceWith from the vanilla HTML DOM object.

Comment: Arash Kazemi - Exactly the solution!! How does the [0] cause the vanilla version to be called, instead of the jQuery version? Also, how are the other browsers 'smart enough' not to experience the same error?

Comment: @Corey: [0] returns the javascript object and not the jquery object in all browsers. Difference is that other browsers implement `replaceWith()` and IE does not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith

Comment: @Corey Yes, exactly as our friend has commented here! Just as an addition, jQuery implements the replaceWith on all platforms. When you use [0], you bypass jQuery and you rely on the browser implementation.